# Calender extender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am using calender extender in my project. But there is some problem in the design of calender extender.

Below is my code and the output design i got.

```
<td align="right">
                From Date:
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDocStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox100" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CaltxtDocStart" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDocStartDate">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
 </td>
```

**Design:**

[image]

What may be the problem i am not getting proper design?

Comment: Need a help m still stuck with it

Answer (score 0):

May be it's because of you have not applied cssClass for calendar control.

check out this and apply proper css for calendar control

http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Custom-Calendar-Control-using-CSS-styles.aspx

Comment: Is there a need to apply css for ajax extension control toolkit?

Comment: It's not necessary to apply css class but calendar control parent element has apply class and may be it's affect calendar design. So I suggest apply css class to calendar or try to remove parent element css class and check result

Comment: K fine let me give a try